# Install apps on Pixelsense

Tags: installation

My company wants to build an application for the Microsoft Pixelsense (ex Surface). But before we start developing a WPF app we would like to build a small demo app in HTML5 just to show the user how the app is going to look like.

They are a bit worried about the web browser on pixelsense and would like to instal Google Chrome on it but don't know if it's possible.

Can someone tell me if it's possible and maybe point me to a page about installing "regular" windows applications on Pixelsense because I wasn't really able to find anything.

Comment: What operating system is on the device exactly.  Its my understanding its just a standard version of Windows.

Comment: It's a standard version of Windows, as far as I know. We haven't got the device yet so we don't know for sure. But as far as I know it's Windows 7. I guess this answeres my question then as well